# How to correctly handle full view resizing in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a view which has numeric values in it, when they get to big to fit the frame, I would like the entire view to have all text in it to resize.  I have added .scaledToFit() after the .frame(width: 150, height:150) , but it still seems to only resize the individual Text String that contains the numeric value, instead of the whole view.  Here's view

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  SampleMRE
//
//  Created by Michael Rowe on 9/10/23.
//

import SwiftUI

var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.isLenient = true
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    return formatter
}()

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                View1()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                View1()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(Color.red)
            }
        }
        .padding(.all, 40)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @State private var floatValue1: Float = 9_9999.0
    @State private var floatValue2: Float = 999_999_999_999.99
    @State private var floatValue3: Float = 999_999_999_999.99
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Heading")
                    .bold()
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Value 1:")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Spacer()
                Text(String(format: "%.0f", floatValue1))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }
            .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
            
            SummaryLine(label: String(localized: "Value 2"), amount: currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue2)) ?? "--")
            SummaryLine(label: String(localized: "Value 3"), amount: currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue3)) ?? "--")
        }
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        .padding(20)
    }
}

struct SummaryLine: View {
    var label: String
    var amount: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(label)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            Spacer()
            Text(amount)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        }
        .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of modifiers is very important and `.scaledToFit` must come before `.frame`.

Try it like this:

```swift
VStack {
    // content as before
}
.minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
.scaledToFit()
.frame(width: 150, height: 150)
.padding(20)
```

If you still see small discrepancies then it may be because of the spacing on the `HStack` and `VStack`. Try using `spacing: 0` on these and then use padding between the items.

Screenshot from iPhone 14 Plus:

[image: Scaled]

Comment: I have tried that, and now the text overlaps between views, and goes outside of the frame.  I've even tried adding .scaledToFit() both before and after the .frame.  (note there are multiple views like above that group together in a larger view, i.e. a 300x150 with two views next to each other.

Comment: It appears that .minimumScaleFactor(0.1).frame(width:150, height:150).scaledToFit() works on iPhone, but on iPad causes the size difference between items.  And moving .scaledtoFit() before .frame causes issues on both.

Comment: I hope you saw my additional note about stack spacing at the bottom (I added it in an edit). Otherwise, I would be happy to investigate further if you could kindly fix the MRE so that it compiles and runs as a standalone example.

Comment: I added colors to make it more obvious - will also try updating to try the spacing: 0

Comment: Thanks for updating the MRE. It works for me when I change the modifiers on the ```VStack``` to the ones I provided (screenshot added to answer). Tried on iPhone 14 Plus and iPad mini 6G (iOS 16.4). I didn't even need to set spacing to 0 on the stacks, although I think there may be small discrepancies as I anticipated, so setting spacing to 0 may help to fix them. If you try it on a very small device then it is conceivable that the minimum scaling factor may need to be made smaller. Note that you are using ```scaledToFill``` in your MRE, very important to replace that line!

Comment: That did it.. and the the .scaledToFill was the main problem!  (seems like an Auto complete issue, that I just didn't catch.  Thank you!  Sometimes it's hard to get a second pair of eyes on your code when you are writing by your self.